# How can I combine a graph, webcam capture (image) and buttons into the same window?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib, tkinter

My code is designed to take an image off of the webcam, display the image, read the RGB colors from multiple pixels OpenCV and then plot those points in a graph (matplotlib).  It all works, but I want to have the image, the graph and the buttons all in the same window, instead of three separate windows.  Can anyone help?

Here is my code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def closeWindow():
    exit()
#def newSample():

def nextSample():
    ramp_frames = 30
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    s, im = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("test11.bmp", im)
    cv2.imwrite("test11.bmp", im)
    
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()
    
    img = cv2.imread('test11.bmp', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    #img1 = PhotoImage(file="C:\Users\Isaac Erickson\Documents\Python\test.bmp")
    plt.gcf().clear()
    
    px1 = im[90,100]
    px2 = im[90,150]
    px3 = im[90,200]
    px4 = im[90,250]
    px5 = im[90,300]
    px6 = im[90,350]
    px7 = im[90,400]
    px8 = im[90,550]  #max 480, 640
    plt.plot(["300","400","450","500","550", "600","650","700"], [px1,px2,px3,px4,px5,px6,px7,px8]) #x and y coordinates
    cv2.imshow('image',im)
    plt.show()    

def reaction():
    ramp_frames = 30
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    s, im = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("test11.bmp", im)
    cv2.imwrite("test11.bmp", im)
    
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cap.release()
    
    img = cv2.imread('test11.bmp', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    plt.gcf().clear()
    
    px1 = im[90,100]
    px2 = im[90,150]
    px3 = im[90,200]
    px4 = im[90,250]
    px5 = im[90,300]
    px6 = im[90,350]
    px7 = im[90,400]
    px8 = im[90,550]  #max 480, 640
    plt.plot(["1","2","3","4","5", "6","7","8"], [px1,px2,px3,px4,px5,px6,px7,px8]) #x and y coordinates
    cv2.imshow('image',im)
    plt.show() 
    

ramp_frames = 30

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
s, im = cap.read()
cv2.imshow("test11.bmp", im)
cv2.imwrite("test11.bmp", im)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()


#Analysis of image
root = Tk()

img = cv2.imread('test11.bmp', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
px1 = im[90,100]
px2 = im[90,150]
px3 = im[90,200]
px4 = im[90,250]
px5 = im[90,300]
px6 = im[90,350]
px7 = im[90,400]
px8 = im[90,550]  #max 480, 640
plt.plot(["300","400","450","500","550", "600","650","700"], [px1,px2,px3,px4,px5,px6,px7,px8]) #x and y coordinates

title = Label(root, text= "VISIBLE COLORS")

p1 = Label(root, text=px1)
p2 = Label(root, text=px2)
p3 = Label(root, text=px3)
p4 = Label(root, text=px4)
p5 = Label(root, text=px5)
p6 = Label(root, text=px6)
p7 = Label(root, text=px7)
p8 = Label(root, text=px8)

title.pack()
p1.pack()
p2.pack()
p3.pack()
p4.pack()
p5.pack()
p6.pack()
p7.pack()
p8.pack()
button1 = Button(root, text="CLOSE", command=closeWindow)
button2 = Button(root, text="Next Sample", command=nextSample)
button3 = Button(root, text="reaction", command=reaction)
button1.pack()
button2.pack()
button3.pack()

print(px1)
print(px2)
print(px3)
print(px4)
print(px5)
print(px6)
print(px7)
print(px8)

cv2.imshow('image',im)
plt.show()
root.mainloop()
cv2.waitKey(0)
cap.release()
#out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks for asking.  I followed this gentleman's YouTube example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HwHqa3tq70

Comment: Here is my code:  mi = PhotoImage(file = "##PATH##Documents\Python\test11.jpg")
button2.config(image=mi,compound=RIGHT

Comment: It still doesn't work.  I get an error:  "Syntax Error: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated ..."